# Android - ArrayAdapter mixed positions?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

**TL;DR** - I have an array adapter, filled by an ArrayList of User object,
and I want to print their order numbers - 1st, 2nd, 3rd... etc
- while scrolling fast back and forth.. those numbers get mixed..

instead of 1,2,3,4 after scrolling fast back and forth I get 1,2,9,4 for example..

I don't get why this happens, I've tried several stuff to solve it but with no success, I even took that text view out of the view holder to see if it helps but no success there too.

here's my adapter:

```
public class HomeHallOfFameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

private HomeFragment fragment;
private ArrayList<User> data;
int page;

public HomeHallOfFameAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> data, HomeFragment fragment, int page) {
    super(context, 0);
    this.data = data;
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.page = page;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data != null ? data.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public User getItem(final int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(final int position) {
    //only used for adapters connected to a cursor.
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyHolder holder = null;

    final User user = data.get(position);

    //initiallize the views
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_frag_hall_of_fame_item, null);
        holder = new MyHolder();

        holder.profileImage1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_hallofame_image);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (MyHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final TextView titleRank = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_hallofame_title);
    final String numberEnding = MainScreenActivity.getInstance().NumberWithSuffix(position+1);
    titleRank.setText(numberEnding);

    loadImage(user.getImages().get(0), holder.profileImage1);

    return convertView;
    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private class MyHolder {
    //TextView titleRank;
    ImageView profileImage1; //fameBlueBtn;
}

}
```

the problem is the titleRank textView..

NumberWithSuffix is just a method that implements the number ending:

```
//method to get the currect number endings.
public String NumberWithSuffix(int number) {

    String outputNumber = "";
    String numberString = String.valueOf(number);

    if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("11")) {
        outputNumber = numberString + "th";
    } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("12")) {
        outputNumber = numberString + "th";
    } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("13")) {
        outputNumber = numberString + "th";
    } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("1")) {
        outputNumber = numberString + "st";
    } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("2")) {
        outputNumber = numberString + "nd";
    } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("3")) {
        outputNumber = numberString + "rd";
    } else {
        outputNumber = numberString + "th";
    }
    return outputNumber.trim();
}
```

any idea what's my problem?

thanks for any help.

Comment: implement viewholder pattern for textview also just like imageview. also what is `MainScreenActivity.getInstance()` ??. you can have your conditions in adapter itself

Comment: you also need to  understand listview recycling mechanism

Comment: I understand the list view recycling mechanism.. I took the textview out of the view holder to try and see if that's the problem,

Comment: MainScreenActivity.getInstance() is used to get to that method as it is used by me from several locations.. wouldn't want to write the same code more then once

Comment: then it shouldn't be in MainActivity it should rather be a Utillity class. You can make that static in utility class and access it and your problem is related to reycling mechanism.

Comment: on that my friend i agree :>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83658/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-jozeri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I've solved this issue..
my code was ok, as I mentioned, it works fine in a vertical list view, but this problem happens in a horizontal list view..
I removed the list view github library i was using and switched to Horizontal Recycler View.. it works great now !

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
MainScreenActivity.getInstance()
```

I assume you instantiate a Activity class here. I suggest you move your `NumberWithSuffix(int number)` to a appropriate Utility class make the method static and you can use the same else where. All your utilities should not be in Activity. Also take care of holding reference to a activity and avoiding memory leaks

Your position of items seems to be fine. I tested your sample and it works fine.

You can make few changes to follow the viewholder pattern as below

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {

MyHolder holder = null;

final User user = data.get(position);

//initiallize the views
if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_frag_hall_of_fame_item, null);
    holder = new MyHolder();

    holder.profileImage1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_hallofame_image);
    holder.titleRank = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_hallofame_title);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {
    holder = (MyHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
final String numberEnding = Utility.NumberWithSuffix(position+1);
holder.titleRank.setText(numberEnding);

loadImage(user.getImages().get(0), holder.profileImage1);

return convertView;

}
```

ViewHolder

```
private static class MyHolder {
    TextView titleRank;
    ImageView profileImage1; //fameBlueBtn;

}
```

Create a Utility class

```
public class Utility {

    public static String NumberWithSuffix(int number) {

        String outputNumber = "";
        String numberString = String.valueOf(number);

        if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("11")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("12")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("13")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("1")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "st";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("2")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "nd";
        } else if (String.valueOf(number).endsWith("3")) {
            outputNumber = numberString + "rd";
        } else {
            outputNumber = numberString + "th";
        }
        return outputNumber.trim();
    }
}
```

Also instead of this

```
final User user = data.get(position);
```

You can use

```
final User user = getItem(position);
```

since you already have

```
@Override
public User getItem(final int position) {
return data.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Hi, first.. thanks a lot for taking your time and trying to help me!

sadly, this still doesn't help. but at least I'm thinking of approaching the problem differently now, tried my code in a "normal" list view.. it works.
so im guessing the problem is with the horizontal list view library i am using.. =\

Comment: I don't know you were using horizontal list

Comment: U can try locus Rocha two way view available on github

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with BaseAdapter with a 2 datasets (or more is you need) and just mix them by type from your datasets in getView()...